# Percentage of time of a time series

Tags: r, matlab, time, timestamp, time-series

I have a series of RPM measurement and each measurement corresponds to time. If I plot the time series of my RPM, it will looks like this:
[image]

The measurements are only recorded when the value are chaning, for example if 21:01 is 0 RPM, and 21:02 is also 0 RPM, the data on 21:02 will not be recorded.

My goal is figure out how to determine the percentage of the time, when the RPM is lower than 1, during the period (8PM to 5AM)?

sample data:

```
# A tibble: 97 x 2
   time                       rpm
   <chr>                    <dbl>
 1 '08/07/2018 08:08:16 PM'    8.
 2 '08/07/2018 08:08:21 PM'    9.
 3 '08/07/2018 08:08:41 PM'    8.
 4 '08/07/2018 08:09:30 PM'    9.
 5 '08/07/2018 08:19:02 PM'   10.
 6 '08/07/2018 08:23:16 PM'    9.
 7 '08/07/2018 08:23:22 PM'   10.
 8 '08/07/2018 08:23:24 PM'    9.
 9 '08/07/2018 08:23:36 PM'    9.
10 '08/07/2018 08:23:45 PM'   10.
# ... with 87 more rows
```

Comment: Can you please include an example of your data, most preferably using `dput(your_data)`?  I would probably approach by adding a variable representing time until next measurement (or end of period), and then add up how much time had RPM < 1.

Comment: I just edit it.

Comment: As @JonSpring said, please add `dput(<your_data>)` or `dput(head(<your_data>))`. We can't reproduce otherwise.

Comment: But what exactly is the problem? Is it a mathematical problem and you wonder what equation has to be used or do you have problems with extraction of the time stamp from the strings or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as pointed out is not very clear, but maybe this could help, using base R:

```
# first you define your time as date
dats$time <-strptime(dats$time, " %d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

# now a lagged vector, that points out the "lasting"
lagged <- c(tail(dats$time , -1),NA)

# here added as column
dats <- cbind(dats, lagged)

dats
                  time rpm              lagged
1  2018-07-08 20:08:16   8 2018-07-08 20:08:21
2  2018-07-08 20:08:21   9 2018-07-08 20:08:41
3  2018-07-08 20:08:41   8 2018-07-08 20:09:30
4  2018-07-08 20:09:30   9 2018-07-08 20:19:02
5  2018-07-08 20:19:02  10 2018-07-08 20:23:16
6  2018-07-08 20:23:16   9 2018-07-08 20:23:22
7  2018-07-08 20:23:22  10 2018-07-08 20:23:24
8  2018-07-08 20:23:24   9 2018-07-08 20:23:36
9  2018-07-08 20:23:36   9 2018-07-08 20:23:45
10 2018-07-08 20:23:45  10                <NA>


# calculate the full time
 overall <- max(dats$time)-min(dats$time)
overall
Time difference of 15.48333 mins

# select only the rpm you want, unluckily due your data, I choose 8, because I do not
# have 1, you can easily change it
dats_rpm <- dats[dats$rpm <= 8,]

# let's calculate each duration of the rpm <= 8
dats_rpm$duration <- dats_rpm$lagged - dats_rpm$time

# lastly the percentage of the duration of rpm<=8 / overall duration
as.double(sum(dats_rpm$duration), units='secs')/as.double(overall, units='secs')*100
[1] 5.812702
```

Hope it helps!

---

With data:

```
dats <-  structure(list(time = c("08/07/2018 08:08:16 PM", "08/07/2018 08:08:21 PM", 
"08/07/2018 08:08:41 PM", "08/07/2018 08:09:30 PM", "08/07/2018 08:19:02 PM", 
"08/07/2018 08:23:16 PM", "08/07/2018 08:23:22 PM", "08/07/2018 08:23:24 PM", 
"08/07/2018 08:23:36 PM", "08/07/2018 08:23:45 PM"), rpm = c(8L, 
9L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```